# How to define strongly-typed, cross-framework configuration in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, configuration, web-config, .net-core

TL;DR: What are the best options for strongly-typed configuration that will work in both .NET Framework and .NET Core web projects?

---

I have a class library project that is used across several internal projects, some in .NET Framework 4.6 and others in .NET Core. To that end, it is designed as a .NET Core project that also builds in .NET Framework.

There is one class in this library that should be serialized in configuration files, and deserialized by the web applications using it. For .NET Core web applications, [no extra work is required on the part of the library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration#using-options-and-configuration-objects).

However, in a new .NET Framework, I want to be able to store multiple versions of this configuration - for development, staging, release etc. - and the best practice for doing this seems to be to create a [custom configuration section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx) for the web.config file, and then store the different versions of the config in `Web.<ConfigurationName>.config`. As the link advises, for this approach the configuration class must extend `ConfigurationSection`, but this is not available in `.NET Standard 1.6.1`, and so I'm at a loss.

In previous .NET Framework projects, I've used a library called [Autofac](https://autofac.org/) to store CLR objects in JSON and deserialize them for configuration, and this worked well. However, I can't find a way to programatically decide between JSON files based on the current environment, whereas working with `Web.config` does this out of the gate.

Any suggestions about how to achieve my aims here would be much appreciated.